# Is UPS Address Verification integrated with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, address, ups

Is there a way to enable UPS address verification in the checkout process?  UPS has a web service that supports this.

Answer (score 1):

Natively there is not. However, there are several extensions that can help you with this such as http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/usps-address-verification.html.